# I want to use.htacess to re-direct only one file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

There's a file that I have that needs to be accessible to an outside source via http. My whole site is https. If I do the following:

```
# Redirect all http traffic to https, only if it is pointed at specialfile.txt
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/specialfile.txt/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/specialfile.txt$1 [R=301,L]
```

Does it look like this would work. I'm an absolute noob when it comes to Apache re-write rules, and I would RTFM but I need this change pretty quick.

I should also mention that there is already

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

in the .htaccess file along with some Wordpress stuff.

Comment: I suggest you simply give it a try and take a look at 1. what happens and 2. (if required) what appears in the error log file.

Comment: I would love to do that, but it's for a live site with no staging server and I really can't afford to take the site down if I do something wrong

Comment: You cannot develop and maintain things without a test environment. I suggest you start setting one up, you will need it again and again. Also it is valuable to limit such rules to a certain IP address or network at first to try them.

Comment: You are 100% correct. And lucky for me, part of my job now includes a Q2 plan for migrating our site to a new hosting company, including building out a staging server. Our current hosting company is crap, so I'm happy. It makes me nervous as hell to do stuff like this on a live site.

Comment: In my company we established a simple rule for that: if a server has been altered in _any_ way from the predefined, automatic setup, that includes _any_ login to the system, it has to be considered unreliable and untrustworthy and has to be removed, a new appliance has to be deployed. I know that way of thinking is a bit overwhelming for people used to think of "servers" in the sense of systems or machines (which makes little sense, actually). And I am not convinced it fits to all situations or tasks, but it is well worth thinking about that point of view...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put something like the following in the root folder `.htaccess` file, it ought to work:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} specialfile.txt$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The directive translates as:

- *If* the URI requested ends in `specialfile.txt`
- Capture all characters (from one to any number) after `https://domain.tld/`
- Rewrite the URI as `http://domain.tld/all-captured-characters`

Comment: Your solution seems obvious and right, but when I try it, curl tells me that the file has permanently moved and Chrome complains that the file has a re-direct loop.

Comment: I made a minor change to what you gave—I had to surround the file name with backslahes, a al ^/specialfile.txt/?.*$ and spell out the full URL in the next line. Not at all sure why, but thanks just the same!